# running two difference method at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run two methods at the same time in Python. One of them plays a sound of a sine wave and the other one measures it. Both methods work fine but I could not figure it out how to start them at the same time.

```
import sounddevice as sd
from numpy import linalg as LA
import numpy as np
from pysine import sine
import time
from threading import Thread
import math

duration = 10 # seconds
def print_sound(indata,outdata, frames, time, status):
    volume_norm = np.linalg.norm(indata)*10
    dB = 20*math.log(volume_norm)
    print (int(dB))

def sine_wave():
    frequency = 5000
    sine(frequency = (frequency),duration = 1.0)
sine_wave()

with sd.Stream(callback=print_sound):
     sd.sleep(duration * 10000)

def main():
    thr1 = Thread(target=print_sound)
    thr2 = Thread(target=sine_wave)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    thr1.start()
    thr2.start()
```

Comment: You probably need to read something about asynchronous coding and async/await syntax in Python, and also something about asyncio.run and asyncio.gather... https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Comment: with this code you should get error message. And you should show this error in question (not in comments) as text.

Comment: Python has `GIL` which block threads and run only one thread. But even if it would run two threads at the same time then system may decide how to execute threads/processes and they don't have to start at the same time. So synchronization can be the problem (in any language)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, if it helps, mark it as answer. Try THIS:

```
import sounddevice as sd
from numpy import linalg as LA
import numpy as np
from pysine import sine
import time
from threading import Thread
import math

duration = 10 # seconds
def print_sound(indata,outdata, frames, time, status):
    volume_norm = np.linalg.norm(indata)*10
    dB = 20*math.log(volume_norm)
    print (int(dB))

def sine_wave():
    frequency = 5000
    sine(frequency = (frequency),duration = 1.0)

with sd.Stream(callback=print_sound):
     sd.sleep(duration * 10000)

def main():
    thr1 = Thread(target=print_sound)
    thr2 = Thread(target=sine_wave)
    thr1.start()
    thr2.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It doesn't start at the same time. print_sound runs after sine_wave have stopped

Comment: @JohnWillson I have updated the code try again

Comment: @JohnWillson Can you clarify, do you want to run functions at the same time or to get output at the same time or both?

Comment: I meant run functions and get output at the same time.